# HDFS Read Write operations at a time

Tags: java, hadoop

I am reading userId's from file which is located in the HDFS . I am reading the file through buffered Reader line by line and appending currentsytemdate to the userId and storing it in the arraylist after end of the file I am writing the array list to the same file. But I don't want add to arraylist  I want to read the line append the currentsystemdate and write to the same file is it possible

Answer (score 0):

HDFS is mostly about "writing once, read many times".If you are trying to update the value better option will be HBase.
In the mapreduce jobs you can use via TableInputFormat and TableOutputFormat.
Hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am reading file test.txt which is located in hdfs and append "Kishore" to every line of this file. Change your logic according to your problem

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public class Append {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.addResource(new Path(
                "/home/kishore/BigData/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"));
        String line = "Kishore";
        Path path = new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/test.txt");
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                fs.append(path)));
        for(int i=0; i< 1000;i++){
            br.write(i+"\n");

        }

        br.close();

    }
}
```